# include Javascript server-side from webcontrol code?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

How can I include Javascript onto my page from a webcontrol that is loading, under the prerender event?

Here's a function I built that I am using, but it is unfortunately not working.

```
/// <summary>
/// Includes a javascript on the page if it is not already included.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="url">The javascript to include on the page.</param>
public static void IncludeJavascript(string url)
{
    string key = MD5.GetMD5Hash(url);
    ClientScriptManager manager = (HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page).ClientScript;
    if (!manager.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered(manager.GetType(), key))
    {
        manager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(manager.GetType(),key, url);
    }
}
```

I am using it like this:

```
ScriptHandler.IncludeJavascript("/scripts/TabControl.js");
```

Is that correct? Or is the path wrong? Does it need to be a server-side path?

The full TabControl I made is this, and as you can see, I am overriding the prerender procedure and using it there. It's just not working:

```
[ToolboxData("<{0}:TabControl Title=\"My tabcontrol\" runat=server>\n<{0}:TabPage Title=\"Default tab\" IsSelected=\"True\">Insert tab page content here ...</{0}:TabPage>\n<{0}:TabPage Title=\"Secondary tab\" IsSelected=\"True\">Insert tab page content here ...</{0}:TabPage>\n</{0}:TabControl>")]
[ParseChildren(false)]
[PersistChildren(true)]
public class TabControl : WebControl
{

    private int count;

    public TabControl()
    {
        count = 0;
    }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptHandler.IncludeJavascript(ResolveUrl("~/scripts/TabControl.js"));
        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }

    [Bindable(true)]
    [Category("Appearance")]
    [DefaultValue("")]
    [Localizable(true)]
    public virtual string Title
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    protected override HtmlTextWriterTag TagKey
    {
        get
        {
            return HtmlTextWriterTag.Div;
        }
    }

    public override string ClientID
    {
        get
        {
            return "tabSectionWrapper";
        }
    }

    private TabPage selectedTab;
    public TabPage SelectedTab
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedTab;
        }
        set
        {
            selectedTab = value;
        }
    }

    protected override void RemovedControl(Control control)
    {
        if (control is TabPage)
        {
            count--;
            base.RemovedControl(control);
        }
    }

    protected override void AddedControl(Control control, int index)
    {
        if (control is TabPage)
        {
            if ((control as TabPage).IsSelected)
            {
                this.SelectedTab = control as TabPage;
            }
            (control as TabPage).ID = "" + count++;
            base.AddedControl(control, index);
        }
    }

    protected override void RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.Write("<div id=\"tabContainer\"><ul class=\"tabs\">");
        foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
        {
            if (control is TabPage)
            {
                (control as TabPage).RenderTitle(writer);
            }
        }
        writer.Write("</ul></div>");
        writer.Write("<div id=\"boxWithContent\">");
        foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
        {
            if (control is TabPage)
            {
                (control as TabPage).RenderControl(writer);
            }
        }
        writer.Write("</div>");
    }

    public override void RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.Write("<h1>");
        writer.WriteEncodedText(this.Title);
        writer.Write("</h1>");
        base.RenderControl(writer);
    }

    protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
    {
        base.RenderContents(output);
    }
}
```

Comment: At what point are you adding the script, it should be in the Page_PreRender event, versus Page_Load.

Comment: I am adding it under a WebControl's prerender event.

Comment: Why not use the url as the key? A hash of the url is not guaranteed to   uniquely identify that string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that the control must be located within a form-control with runat="server" specified. I thought any control with runat="server" specified would be enough, but no.

Wow. Just wow.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a relative path that takes into account the virtual directory your site might be running under:

```
IncludeJavascript(ResolveUrl("~/scripts/TabControl.js"));
```

Comment: @Mathias Lykkegaard Lorenzen, when you look at the generated HTML page source do you see the script inclusion: `<script src="/scripts/TabControl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`?

Comment: Nope, that's exactly what I'm not seeing :(

Comment: @Mathias Lykkegaard Lorenzen, where are you calling this method? I wrote a simple ASP.NET application and in the `Page_Load` of the default webform I called the function and the script was correctly added. The only thing I changed was `MD5.GetMD5Hash(url)` => `var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(MD5.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(url)))` as there is no a static `GetMD5Hash` method that I am aware of on the [MD5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5.aspx) class.

Comment: I am calling it from a custom webcontrol that is loading, by overriding the OnPreRender procedure. It is being triggered. It just doesn't work.

Comment: @Mathias Lykkegaard Lorenzen, could you please show the code you are using to call this method? The exact location and method.

Comment: I changed the original post to reflect such changes Darin. Could you have a look at it again?

Comment: @Mathias Lykkegaard Lorenzen, I have tested your code by integrating the web control in a web page and it successfully added the script tag inside the resulting HTML.

Comment: Strange. Maybe it's my master page? Are there any requirements to the master page?

Comment: @Mathias Lykkegaard Lorenzen, maybe you could isolate the problem into a simple project that you could send me so that I can take a look at what might be wrong with it?

Comment: That would be way too much work for me. The problem is hard to isolate since it involves much more code than you have seen already.